# Adding filter on the right side table on Left outer joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, right-join

On outer joins(lets take a left outer join in this case) how does adding a filter on the right side table work?

```
SELECT s.id, i.name FROM Student s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Instructor i
ON s.student_id=i.student_id
AND i.name='John'
```

I understand that if the filter was on the `Student` table it would be more like "Get all rows with name= John first and join the tables".

But I am not sure if that is the case if the filter is on the right side table(`Student_Instructor`). How does the filter `i.name='John'` gets interpreted?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on where the filter is applied in the JOIN condition or the WHERE clause.

Comment: @user2989408 the filter is applied in the JOIN condition as shown in the example.

Comment: Type EXPLAIN before your select to see the query plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rows will be returned from your left table regardless. In the case of a left join, if the filter isn't met, all data returned from the right table will show up as null. In your case, all students will show up in your results. If the student doesn't have an instructor, i.name will be null.

Since you are only selecting a column from your left table, your join is pretty useless. I would also add i.name to your select, so you can see the results

In the case of an inner join, rows will only be returned if the join filter is met.

Answer (score 11):

Should be the same as:

```
SELECT s.id FROM Student s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select * from Student_Instructor where name='John' ) i
ON s.student_id=i.student_id
```

Comment: Also, can provide some examples if needed.

Comment: This is the correct answer: the static join condition on the right side table is a filter on the table prior to the join. I tested this on sample data to be sure. Adam's point is correct, but now that `i.name` was added to the select in the example this answers the question of how join conditions alter the right side of the join.

Answer (score 3):

In your example query, only rows where i.name = 'John' would be returned.  I think you would want to also include **or i.name is null** to include all rows where a Student record does include a student Instructor.

```
SELECT s.id FROM Student s , isnull(i.name, 'No Student Insturctor') as [Student Instructor]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Instructor i
ON s.student_id=i.student_id
AND i.name='John' or i.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Oracle (+) notation as well-

```
SELECT s.id FROM Student s, Student_Instructor i
WHERE s.student_id = i.student_id (+)
AND i.name(+)='John'
```

Although, Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator.